# Replaced Inefficient Javascript with JQuery with language errors

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In the process of trying to be more efficient I have been learning a bit of JQuery, but obviously don't know enough.

I need a script that will get each checked function $(':checked').each(function() . Then if a hidden field id (combined with this fields alt tag's) title is not equal to this check boxes title to perform jquery load.

I could go on with trying to explain this but I would rather show what I mean. If you look at the code below the 2 elements which cannot exist are :alt and :title. If you can see what I'm trying to do then any ideas how I would get it working. Data driven site has left me few alternatives.

```
function product_analysis_global() {
    $(':checked').each(function () {
        if ($('#product_quantity_PRI_' + ':alt').title != ':title') {
            $('#product_' + ':alt').load(':title');
            $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + ':alt').title = ':title';
            $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + ':alt').value = ':value';
        } else if ($('#product_quantity_PRI_' + ':alt').title != 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html') {
            $('#product_' + ':alt').load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html');
            $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + ':alt').title = 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html';
        } else
        return false;
    });
}
```

Many Thanks,

ps. Implementation can be seen here where by the radio buttons and checkboxes should load in the appropriate products. You will need to click on Beginners to load the form.
http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adventure-training

Comment: Inside the `each()` function you are not using the jQuery function at all correctly.  What is the purpose of the `':alt'` and `':title'` parts?  Also do your IDs actually end in underscores?  The `.load()` function is an AJAX function that fills in content from an external file, so `.load(':title')` won't go far.  There are no `.title` and `.value` properties to my knowledge.  Write in pseudocode what you want to achieve.

Comment: What is this: `$('#product_' + ':alt').load(':title');` supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry chaps. The form does not load in unless you http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adventure-training and then click on beginners.

Comment: The site is very nice, but have you got enough resources loading in the `<head>`!  I would seriously consider combining some of those JS files where possible and see if you need all of them on every page.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please format your code so others can easily read it when asking for help.

Your description isn't exactly clear, and the page you linked to has no radio buttons or checkboxes, but I believe you are looking for:

```
function product_analysis_global() { 
    $(':checked').each(function() {
        var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        if ($('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).attr('title') != title) {
            $('#product_' + alt).load(title); 
            $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).attr('title', title); 
            $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).val($(this).val()); 
        } else if ($('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).attr('title') != 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html') { 
            $('#product_' + alt).load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html'); 
            $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + alt).attr('title', 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank2.html'); 
        } else return false ; 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Hello, This code is very good however it is producing unexpected results. I believe the problem may be with the $(this).attr('alt'). It would need to take the alt attribute of each element not only the one clicked on. Have a look if possible and you will see what I mean. http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adventure-training and then click on BEGINNERS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit lost. On your example page I see no instances of checkboxes or radio buttons? **:checked** can only be used with these elements. Perhaps you can do a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) and give a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: My apologies. The form does not load that way. GO here http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adventure-training and then click on beginners. Then the form loads in